# boost c++ libraries: sleep_for wait (almost) twice

Tags: c++, boost, boost-thread

I'm using the Boost C++ Libraries but I've some problems with `sleep_for` function: it takes very long time!!! If I want to sleep a thread for just 1 second it sleep the thread for 2 seconds!!!

I'm using msvc 2010 as compiler in a on Windows 7 (x64). The libraries are compiled in x86 istruction set.
My application has about 5 threads and I don't want replace (if possible) with a Sleep call because I'm using interruption points.

Have I some altenatives? I

Som example:

```
static const boost::chrono::microseconds timeToSleep( 40000 );

DWORD dwStart = timeGetTime();
boost::this_thread::sleep_for( timeToSleep );
DWORD elapsed = timeGetTime() - dwStart;
BOOST_LOG_TRIVIAL( trace ) << "elapsed: " << elapsed << "ms" << std::endl;
```

this print always 80 the double

If I write:

```
static const boost::chrono::microseconds timeToSleep( 80000 );
```

In few word if I want sleep x it sleeps 2x. I've switched between Debug and Release mode but I've the same result. 
Am I wron something??? This is very strange

**edit**

```
#define BOOST_TEST_MODULE SLEEP_FOR_TEST_SUIT
#include <boost/test/unit_test.hpp>
#include <boost/log/trivial.hpp>
#include <boost/thread.hpp>

#include <Windows.h>
#include <MMSystem.h>
#pragma comment( lib, "Winmm.lib" )

using namespace boost;


BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE( sleep_test )
{
    for ( int i = 0; i < 1000000; i += 10000 )
    {
        chrono::microseconds toSleep( i );
        DWORD dwStart = timeGetTime();
        this_thread::sleep_for( toSleep );
        BOOST_LOG_TRIVIAL( info )
            << "this_thread::sleep_for( chrono::microseconds( " << i / 1000 << " ) has slept: "
            << timeGetTime() - dwStart << "ms";
    }
}
```

this always sleep twice

Comment: `In few word if I want sleep x it sleeps 2x.` Why dont you tell it to sleep `x/2`?

Comment: @Arthur, What kind of solution is that?

Comment: @Arthur: Without understanding where the mysterious factor of 2 is coming from, there's no way to know whether bodging the input will reliably give the desired output.

Comment: I'll write a simple single thread application with sleep_for test

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use the boost 1.53, then it is a [boost bug](https://svn.boost.org/trac/boost/ticket/8136). A solution is either to patch the boost sources, to wait a new release or to rollback to a previous boost version.

Comment: It's strange to see this kind of bugs on boost. Seems they don't test their libraries!